# How to update a LayoutUnit in PrimeFaces using rendered?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to  show a form in the `layoutUnit center` when I click in the `p:commandButton` in the left side using `rendered`, I tried with this code but It didn't work:

test.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <p:layout fullPage="true" >
        <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Tableau de bord">
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton  actionListener="#{userBean.formClient}" value="Client" />
            </h:form> 
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center" >
            <p:panel id="panelClient" rendered="#{userBean.showFormClt}">
                <h1>Testing</h1>
            </p:panel>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
```

UserBean.java

```
private boolean showFormClt;

 public boolean isShowFormClt() {
    return showFormClt;
}

public void setShowFormClt(boolean showFormClt) {
    this.showFormClt = showFormClt;
}

public void formClient(ActionEvent e){
   showFormClt = true;
}
```

Comment: You nowhere even to try to update something inside the center layoutunit, so it is no wonder it dpes not work

Comment: Thank you for the reply, do you have any solution ?

Comment: Yes, learn ajax (and the accepted answer has several bad things in it, although it 'works' don't take it as a good example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just use `ajax="false"` :

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{userBean.formClient}" 
                 value="Client" ajax="false"/>
```

Comment: @mak_doni try with `ajax="false"` i edit my answer hope that help you

Comment: Bad suggestion... a form around the layout is a 'god form' and prome to result in errors. And it should work with ajax too...and update is useless when not doing ajax

Comment: you are right @Kukeltje i mixed many information, i arrive to make it work just with `ajax="false"` i can't make it work with `update` can you share a solution using update, and you have my up-vote?

Comment: Start reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo and make sure if things do not work to always run in development mode and have messages component in your page that is updated (best via autoupdate)